# Socket.io + nginx + SSL = *31 upstream prematurely closed connection

Tags: node.js, ssl, nginx, websocket, socket.io

I am trying to run a Node.js server (with socket.io) as a pub/sub server for my main app. I pushed it to the server and created a subdomain (with SSL). My client HTML page can load the `socket.io/socket.io.js`, but the WSS handshake dont work as expected:

```
WebSocket connection to 

'wss://ws.example.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=ogEegJXhjFh5lplgAAAF' 

failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 502
```

I've got a **SSL** subdomain defined in my **nginx** like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 default ssl;
    server_name ws.example.com;

    # ssl on;
    ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/certificates/certificate-ws-example-com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certificates/ws.example.com.key;

    # Redirect all non-SSL traffic to SSL.
    if ($ssl_protocol = "") {
        rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:6969;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/example_production.access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/example_production.error.log;
    }
}
```

And my **Node.js** (pm2) server responds me:

```
[error] 29726#0: *31 upstream prematurely closed connection
while reading response header from upstream, 

  client: 86.228.47.218, 
  server: ws.example.com, 
  request: 
    "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=ogEegJXhjFh5lplgAAAF HTTP/1.1",
  upstream: 
    "http://127.0.0.1:6969/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=ogEegJXhjFh5lplgAAAF", 
  host: "ws.example.com"
```